# How to use this in jquery design patterns

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to understand some basics in design patterns.
For this i created a object. Now i would like to get and set a name.

How to use `this` in this pattern ? 
Unfortunately my code is not working.
What is the best way to get the properties inside a class/method.

```js
var myClass = (function() {
  var name = ''; //private properties

  function getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  function setName(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  var obj = { // constructor method
    getName: getName, // public properties
    setName: setName,
  }

  return obj;
})();



$(document).ready(function() {
  myClass.setName("Greg");
  var name = myClass.getName();
  console.log(name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: All the methods inside the anonymous function used to return the job, have access to the variables declared inside that function.  There is no need to use a `this`.  You can just reference those private variables.

Comment: I placed your code in an executable snippet where it appears to work fine, for a single instance at least. That said, I'd suggest you follow [this](http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/) kind of pattern if you want to utilise OOP in JS

Comment: Your code returns an object that has 2 parameters, but no parameter that is called `name`, even though you refer to it in your functions. You probably need to add a `name` field in the `obj` object, so that this field can keep the state set and get field are trying to use.

Comment: @Glubus that would completely defeat the point of the private variable, though